# How would I execute a stored procedure from an implementation of EmptyInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have an implementation of [`EmptyInterceptor`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html) defined as a [`@Component`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) that sets some fields on save or update. In certain situations for a delete, I'd like to run a stored procedure before the delete happens. I was trying to use the `EntityManager` to executed the procedure but I am not able to inject the `PersistenceContext` using:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

This is because my implementation of `EmptyInterceptor` is `@Autowired` into my `Config` class that creates our `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. The interceptor is used when the entity manager factory is created so I get a circular dependency if I try to inject the `EntityManager` into the interceptor:

```
16:07:28,526 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private x.y.z.MyInterceptor x.y.z.MyConfig.myInterceptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myInterceptor': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
16:07:28,535 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private x.y.z.MyInterceptor x.y.z.MyConfig.myInterceptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myInterceptor': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

If I can't get to the `EntityManager` to execute my stored procedure, what are my alternatives? I am looking into getting the `EntityManager` in my `Config` class and adding it as a field on the interceptor but that seems like it could get nasty.